# Gradient descent algorithm

Tags: algorithms, vector-analysis, gradient-descent

I'm trying to understand how the *Gradient Descent Algorithm* works.
There is a formula that I found on Wikipedia and that I can not justify:

https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Gradient_descent#/Solution_of_a_non-linear_system

It is the formula that gives the Gradient of F in the paragraph *Solution Of A non-Linear System* that I don't understand.

[image: formula]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please make the question self-contained by including the formula you're asking about. Links may go stale, leaving the question unintelligible for later users of the site.

Comment: Is it this part of the article; $\nabla F(\mathbf{x})=2A^T(A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b})$ ?

Comment: It's a generalization of what happens with one variable: $(f^2)'=2f'f$.

Comment: Thank you batgol for your answer, that's what crossed my mind but I can't write it down in a "proper" way. How exactly is it done?